# How to compare columns and add a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
fruit      color  country
Apple      red    india
Apple      green  china 
banana     yellow  Aus  
banana     green   USA      
grapes     black   China  
grapes     green   korea
grapes     red     japan
grapes     white   USA
grapes     yellow  Aus
Orange     orange  INDIa
Orange     green   India
```

IF if two records fruit column is equal then check the country column if any column has INDIA then print IPL, doesnot contains India then print NON -IPL , if all are India then print ALL-IPL IN NEXT NEW column category.

required output is

```
fruit       category
Apple        IPL
banana       Non-IPL
grapes       Non-IPL
Orange       All-IPL
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to lowercase by [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html), compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then aggregate [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html)
[`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html), last use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for set categories:

```
df1 = df['country'].str.lower().eq('india').groupby(df['fruit']).agg(['any','all'])

masks = [df1['all'], df1['any'] & ~df1['all']]
vals = ['All-IPL','IPL']

cats = np.select(masks, vals, default='Non-IPL')
print (cats)
['IPL' 'All-IPL' 'Non-IPL' 'Non-IPL']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': df1.index, 'Category':cats})
print (df2)
    Fruit Category
0   Apple      IPL
1  Orange  All-IPL
2  banana  Non-IPL
3  grapes  Non-IPL
```